# How do I fix bluetooth not working?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, bluetooth

I own the raspberry pi 3. I've had it since like mid-late August. I was so happy about bluetooth. After a while, it stopped working. I checked the circuit board and the built in bluetooth board for damage and there was no dust or damage.
I went into the startup script and it said it couldn't startup and configure the bluetooth service and the bluetooth modem. How do I fix this? I have the latest software and firmware.